# Are generic function wrappers in C++ possible?

Tags: c++, functional-programming, generic-programming, decltype

This came up when I was looking into a bug in the `boost::fusion::fused` function wrapper when using decltype. The issue seems to be that an invalid decltype is a compile error, even if the template instantiation that requires it will not be used, and I cannot figure out how to get around that to create a generic function wrapper.

Here's my attempt at the single-argument wrapper:

```
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

template <class T>
typename std::add_rvalue_reference<T>::type declval();

template <class Fn, class Arg>
struct get_return_type
{
    typedef decltype(declval<Fn>()(declval<Arg>())) type;
};

template <class Fn>
struct wrapper
{
    explicit wrapper(Fn fn) : fn(fn) {}
    Fn fn;

    template <class Arg>
    typename get_return_type<Fn,Arg&&>::type
        operator()(Arg&& arg)
    {
        return fn(std::forward<Arg>(arg));
    }

    template <class Arg>
    typename get_return_type<const Fn,Arg&&>::type
        operator()(Arg&& arg)
    {
        return fn(std::forward<Arg>(arg));
    }
};
```

The trouble is, this doesn't work for cases where the arguments to the non-const version are not convertible to the arguments for the const version. For example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct x {};
struct y {};

struct foo
{
    void operator()(x) { std::cout << "void operator()(x)" << std::endl; }
    void operator()(y) const { std::cout << "void operator()(y) const" << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    wrapper<foo> b = wrapper<foo>(foo());
    b(x()); // fail
}
```

It seems to me that the failure of the decltype expression caused by `void operator()(y) const` should simply result in that function being removed due to SFINAE.

Comment: shouldn't there be a return in your operators for the wrapper?

Comment: @VJovic Whoops! Thanks, I've added them now.

Comment: Also the 2nd operator() in the wrapper should be const. What compiler? What is the error? For g++ 4.6.1 I get some weird error : `no match for call to (const foo)(x)`

Comment: I've tried this with g++ 4.7 and VS2010. Both fail the same way - the template instantiation `get_return_type<const Fn,Arg&&>::type` fails and, instead of being removed due to SFINAE, it causes a compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that compiles fine on g++ 4.6.1 :

```
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template <class Fn, class Arg>
struct get_return_type
{
    typedef decltype( std::declval<Fn>() ( std::declval<Arg>() ) ) type;
};

template <class Fn>
struct wrapper
{
    explicit wrapper(Fn fn) : fn(fn) {}
    Fn fn;

    template <class Arg>
    typename get_return_type<Fn,Arg&&>::type
    operator()(Arg&& arg)
    {
        return fn(std::forward<Arg>(arg));
    }

    template <class Arg>
    typename get_return_type< const Fn,Arg&&>::type
    operator()(Arg&& arg) const
    {
        return fn(std::forward<Arg>(arg));
    }
};

struct x {};
struct y {};

struct foo
{
    x* operator()(x) { std::cout << "x* operator()(x)" << std::endl; return nullptr; }
    x operator()(x) const { std::cout << "x operator()(x) const" << std::endl; return x(); }
    y* operator()(y) { std::cout << "y* operator()(y)" << std::endl; return nullptr; }
    y operator()(y) const { std::cout << "y operator()(y) const" << std::endl; return y(); }
};

template <class Fn>
void test_foo(Fn fn)
{
    // make sure all operator() overloads are callable
    const Fn& cfn = fn;

    x* a = fn(x());
    x b = cfn(x());
    y* c = fn(y());
    y d = cfn(y());
(void)a;(void)b;(void)c;(void)d;
}

int main()
{
    test_foo(foo());
    test_foo(wrapper<foo>(foo())); // fail
}
```

Comment: Well, if you change the functor, then sure, but the point is can a function wrapper be written that can wrap every function?

Comment: @Ayjay The above code is fixed version that compiles fine for both x and y :)

Comment: But now it doesn't correctly determine the return type of a `const` functor.

Comment: @Ayjay what is expected? what you got?

Comment: @BЈовић I want the wrapper class to be able to wrap any function object that contains an arbitrary amount of `operator()` overloads. As long as a valid overload is called by the callee, it should work.

Comment: @Ayjay I tried different operator() signatures, and every one worked.

Comment: @Ayjay I coped and pasted your example, modified it a bit, and it works. Find the corrected version in the edit